# How are the values printed in the foreach statement?

Tags: perl, foreach

I am very very new to perl programming.

While reading about the loops, for the foreach loop I got two examples.

The one example is,

```
foreach ('hickory','dickory','doc') {
   print $_;
   print "\n";
}
```

Output:-

```
hickory
dickory
doc
```

The $_ variable contains the each item. So, it prints.

In another example, they said did not specified the $_ variable in print statement. The empty print statement only there. How it prints the foreach arguments.

```
foreach ('hickory','dickory','doc') {
   print;
   print "\n";
}
```

Output:-

```
hickory
dickory
doc
```

For this also the same output. How it prints the values. In that book they did not given any explanation for that. I was searched in internet. But I am not able to find anything.

Comment: See [perldoc -f print](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) : *If LIST is omitted, prints $_ to the currently selected output handle.* `$_` is the default argument for print, meaning that if you just call `print` without argument, `$_` gets printed.

Comment: See about `$_` in [General Variables in perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables). There are _many_ things in Perl that use it as default, and it is one of _the_ most common devices.

Comment: Is anyone going to write an answer? It's a valid question, though reading the docs should be enough. Just finding that specific doc is hard. We basically have the answer with the comments above, but comments are not for answers. I'm going to wait in case one of you guys decides to write the answer.

Comment: So I did @simbabque

Comment: @simbabque  Thanks for prompting for answers, you were completely right. The question at first appeared to me as right out of docs, but it did need and warrant proper answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question about `print` in `foreach` being answered, here is a little more on `$_`.

From [General Variables in perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables)

> Here are the places where Perl will assume `$_` even if you don't use it:
>
> - The following functions use `$_` as a default argument:
>
> ```
> - abs, alarm, chomp, chop, chr, chroot, cos, defined, eval, evalbytes, exp, fc, glob, hex, int, lc, lcfirst, length, log, lstat, mkdir, oct, ord, pos, print, printf, quotemeta, readlink, readpipe, ref, require, reverse (in scalar context only), rmdir, say, sin, split (for its second argument), sqrt, stat, study, uc, ucfirst, unlink, unpack.
> ```
>
> - All file tests (`-f` , `-d` ) except for `-t` , which defaults to STDIN. See [`-X`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)
> - The pattern matching operations `m//`, `s///` and `tr///` (aka `y///`) when used without an `=~` operator.
> - The default iterator variable in a `foreach` loop if no other variable is supplied.
> - The implicit iterator variable in the `grep()` and `map()` functions.
> - The implicit variable of `given()`.
> - The default place to put the next value or input record when a `<FH>`, `readline`, `readdir` or `each` operation's result is tested by itself as the sole criterion of a `while` test. Outside a `while` test, this will not happen.
> - `$_` is by default a global variable.

As you can see, it is available nearly everywhere and it is indeed used a lot. Note that the [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) page describes a whole lot more of similar variables, many of them good to know about.

Here is an example.  Consider that we read lines from a file, want to discard the ones which have only spaces or start with `#` (comments), and for others want to split them by spaces into words.

```
open my $fh, '<', $file  or die "Can't open $file: $!";

while (<$fh>) 
{
    next if not /\S/;
    next if /^\s*#/;

    my @words = split;

    # do something with @words ...
}
```

Let's see how many uses of `$_` are in the above example.  Here is an equivalent program

```
while (my $line = <$fh>) 
{
    next if not $line =~ m/\S/;    # if not matching any non-space character
    next if $line =~ m/^\s*#/;     # if matching # after only (possible) spaces

    my @words = split ' ', $line;  # split $line by ' ' (any white space)

    # do something with @words ...
}
```

Compare these two

- the filehandle read `<$fh>` in the `while` condition assigns to `$_`, then available in the loop.
- regular expression's *match operator* by default works on `$_`. The `m` itself can be dropped.
- `split` by default splits `$_`.  We also use the other default, for the pattern to split the string by, which is `' '` (any amount of any white space).
- once we do `$line = <$fh>` the deal with `$_` is off (it is undefined in the loop) and we have to use `$line` everywhere.  So *either* do this *or* do `while (<$fh>)` and use `$_`.

To illustrate all this a bit further, let us find the longest capitalized word on each line

```
use List::Util 'max';

my $longest_cap = max map { length } grep { /^[A-Z]/ } @words;
```

The [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) takes the list in `@words` and applies the block to each element. Each element is assigned to `$_` and is thus available to the code inside the block as `$_`. This is what the regex uses by default. The ones that satisfy the condition are  passed to [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html), which also iterates assigning them to `$_`, what is of course the default for [length](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length.html). Finally `max` from [List::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html) picks the largest one.

Note that `$_` is never actually written and no temporary variable is needed.

Here is some of the relevant documentation.  The [I/O Operators in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators) discusses `while (<$fh>)` and all manner of related things. The regex part is in [Regexp Quote-Like Operators in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) and in [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html). Also have a look at [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html).

---

Defaults are used regularly and to read code written by others you must understand them.  When you *write* your own code though you can choose whether to use `$_` or not, as one can always introduce a lexical variable instead of it.

So, when to use `$_` as default (which need not be written) and when not to?

Correct use of defaults, `$_` in particular, can lead to clearer and more readable code. What generally means *better* code. But it is quite possible to push this too far and end up with obscure, tricky, and brittle code. So good taste is required when deciding.

Another case is when some parts of the code benefit from having `$_` for their defaults while at other places you then have to use `$_` explicitly. I'd say that if `$_` is seen more than once or twice in a section of code it means that there should be a properly named variable instead.

Overall, if in any doubt simply name everything.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not declaring any variable in your `foreach` loop it sets by default `$_`

From [perldoc about foreach](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.18.0/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops):

> The foreach keyword is actually a synonym for the for keyword, so you
>   can use either. If VAR is omitted, $_ is set to each value.

So it explains the first loop.

The second loop, as you already know now that `$_` is set with each element from your array, will works because you are omitting the $`var`.

You could use foreach loop with explicit variable like this:

```
foreach my $item ( @list )
{

 print "My item is: $item\n";

}
```

Or you can omit like you did and  [print](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html)  will still work as @Dada said because:

> If FILEHANDLE is omitted, prints to the last selected (see select)
>   output handle. If LIST is omitted, prints $_ to the currently selected
>   output handle.

Answer (score 0):

I will explain why you getting same results with the different syntax:

If you omit the control variable from the beginning of the foreach
loop, Perl uses its favorite default variable, $_ . This is (mostly) just like any other scalar variable, except for its unusual name. For example:

```
foreach ('hickory','dickory','doc') {
  print $_;
  print "\n";
}
```

Output :

```
hickory
dickory
doc
```

Although this isn’t Perl’s only default by a long shot, it’s Perl’s most common default. You’ll see many other cases in which Perl will automatically use $_ when you don’t tell it to use some other variable or value, thereby saving the programmer from the heavy labor of having to think up and type a new variable name. So as not to keep you in suspense, one of those cases is 
print , which will print $_ if given no other argument:

```
foreach ('hickory','dickory','doc') {
  print; # prints $_ by default
  print "\n";
}
```

Output :-

```
hickory
dickory
doc
```